# how to get name of app where my share extension is used?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I am working on share extension and I want the name of the application where my `share extension` is clicked.

If I click on whatsApp sharer(or UIActivityViewController) then a list of shareVia apps displays, there

- if I clicked on fb then I need to get "whatsApp".
- if I clicked on mail then I need to get "whatsApp".
- if I clicked on WhatsApp I need to get "WhatsApp".

I've gone through many links in stack overflow but couldn't find results that I need.

I've used below code,

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey]
```

here it only returns my share extension name, but I want the name of application where my share extension is used.

OR

Share Extension that must work for only one particular app. Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That information is not available.